# Python absolute import in module fails

Tags: python, importerror, python-import

I have a project which looks like this:

```
my_project/
          __init__.py -- empty
          run.py
          datacheck/
                  __init__.py -- empty
                  datacheck.py -- containing class DataCheck(object)
                  config.py -- containing BusinessConfig(object)
                  business.py -- containing class BusinessCheck(DataCheck)
```

My `PYTHONPATH` is configured to have /my_project in it.

In run.py, I have the following code:

```
from datacheck.business import BusinessCheck
business = BusinessCheck()
business.check_data()
```

In business.py, I have the following imports that fail:

```
from datacheck.config import BusinessConfig
from datacheck.datacheck import DataCheck
```

A relative import like `from .config import BusinessConfig` works - however I've read in numerous threads that an absolute import is preferred.

To do a simple test, I also created the following:

```
myproject/
          __init__.py -- empty
          run_test.py
          test/
              __init__.py -- empty
              test1.py -- containing class Test1(object)
              test2.py -- containing class Test2(Test1)
```

run_test.py imports and runs the `Test2` class, this didn't fail.

It left me a bit flabbergasted, I don't understand why my absolute imports in datacheck are not working - can anyone explain?

Comment: `from datacheck.business import Business` but `business.py -- containing class BusinessCheck(DataCheck)`... Where is the class `Business`?

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` file in `datacheck` too? This file makes the directory a package, and can be empty.

Comment: @eumiro: Sorry, little mistake - correct it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should prefer absolute imports if your module can be used as `__main__`, as explained in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references). If not, relative imports are fine.

These imports fail, because your package `datacheck` contains a module `datacheck` (same name). When looking up the name, Python implicitly looks inside the package first. There, it finds the module `datacheck`. This module, however, does not contain anything with the name `config`, so the import fails.

If you want to use absolute imports, move all the stuff from the module `datacheck` into the `__init__.py` of the package, or rename it.

Comment: That (datacheck in datacheck) was it all along, I never knew this wasn't possible! Thanks a bunch :-)

Comment: @SjaakTrekhaak: It is possible, but it creates an ambiguity, so you have to extra careful.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is many years later, but for the sake of others searching here, I was able to resolve a similar problem with this bit of code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

After that, absolute imports worked fine in Python 2.6 and 2.7.